# Is there a C# way to obtain the Azure domain from the BlobContainerClient?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

C#

Visual Studio 2022

I use the BlobContainerClient to get the list of blobs in my Azure Storage Account container. That's pretty mutch boilerplate code...

However, the link that I can create to the blob via code, which is identical to the one listed in the Azure container for the blob, cannot be used to pull the file:

```
            var resultSegment = container.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(prefix: prefix, delimiter: "/")
                .AsPages(default, 50);


            // Enumerate the blobs returned for each page.
            await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobHierarchyItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
            {
                // A hierarchical listing may return both virtual directories and blobs.
                foreach (BlobHierarchyItem blobhierarchyItem in blobPage.Values)
                {     
                    url = $"{container.Uri}/{blobhierarchyItem.Blob.Name}");
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Which translate roughly to :

```
https://someappclients.blob.core.windows.net/$mycontainer/somepath/somefile.pdf
```

I get

```
<Error>
    <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
    <Message>The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:b3002409-901e-009e-38dd-0858d9000000 Time:2022-12-05T19:11:59.4423847Z</Message>
</Error>
```

But the real domain for the site file that will allow download is :

https://a-nice-prefix.the-real-domain.com/somepath/somefile.pdf

So, either via the BlobServiceClient, or the BlobContainerClient (or some admin API for Azure?) can I find the matching real domain for this blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

*Initially I tried with same as like your Blob URL and got same error in private container:*

```
https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/demo/sample2.docx
```

**Console:**

[image]

If you need access blob storage in private container you need to give **`URL + SAS token`** in your browser.

You can generate SAS token with Blob URL using C#

Before using code make sure you have assigned role like **storage-blob-contributor role.**

Go to portal -> storage accounts -> Access Control (IAM)-> Add role assignments -> storage-blob-contributor to your principal.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
namespace SAStoken
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var storageAccountUriString = $"https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net";
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(storageAccountUriString), credential);

            var userDelegationKey = blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKey(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1));


            var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");  //container name
            var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("demo/sample2.docx"); // my image blob name

            var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = blobClient.BlobContainerName,
                BlobName = blobClient.Name,
                Resource = "b", // b for blob, c for container
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(4),
            };
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read); // read permissions

            BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(blobClient.Uri)
            {
                // Specify the user delegation key.
                Sas = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(userDelegationKey, blobServiceClient.AccountName)
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Blob SAS URI: {0}", blobUriBuilder);
        }

    }
}
```

**Portal:**
In portal, I have a pdf file in my blob storage.

[image]

**Console:**
I tried above code which executed successfully with **`blob Url + SAS token.`**

[image]

I checked the URL + SAS token in the browser it worked perfectly.

**Browser**

[image]

If you need to access container through public(container) you will access the file:

[image]

**Browser:**

[image]

Comment: One of the more thorough answers I've seen. Thanks

Comment: It's useful to be sure, but it doesn't answer the question posed. I've decided to use this approach as I need to move forward, thus the acceptance